# MediaWiki: skin and extentions files missing

Tags: arch-linux, mediawiki

I have an Arch Mediawiki installation that refers to several extensions and skins like this in a file called LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/WikiEditor/WikiEditor.php" );
require_once ( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/extensions/Cite/Cite.php" );
require_once "$IP/skins/CologneBlue/CologneBlue.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/Modern/Modern.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/Timeless/SkinTimeless.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/MonoBook/MonoBook.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/Vector/Vector.php";
```

It has worked until the last time I visited my wiki, but yesterday it wouldn't show anything unless I commented out all these lines. It appeared all these php files have vashished:

```
$ ls /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/skins/Vector/ | grep Vektor.php
$
```

Even in the source tree, the files are not there: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-skins-Vector

I assume that I missed some info when last updating my Mediawiki using pacman.

Can someone tell me if the way to refer to skins and extensions in mediawiki has changed, and how?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading skins and extensions via their PHP entry points has been deprecated since 1.25 (and apparently hard-removed from a bunch of them recently). Instead, your config file should look like

```
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
wfLoadSkin( 'CologneBlue' );
```

which loads skins/extensions via their `skin.json` / `extension.json` files.